Android applications battery usage monitor
I am developing an android application which get the battery usage of installed application to compare these information with screen usage and find if there is a hidden battery hunter or not! I need battery usage from last unplugged or special duration. There are some applications like Gsam battery monitor or AccuBattery which do this right now but I can't get what they do!!
I've just found some old solution which use hidden API but they don't support monitoring special application and just get average usage.
Is there any idea how to do it?
